# What does the school do?

Tags: anime-studio-story

One of the facilities you can rent/purchase is called the School and its description/bonus is simply "Recruit promising students".

I have had the school installed for quite a while and have had an open employee slot thinking it would "create" an employee. It has done nothing of the sort.

What does the school facility actually do?

Comment: I suspect it will allow you to hire better candidates, but I don't know, because I don't have that facility.

Comment: no option has come up to "hire from school" or anything like. and the staff choices haven't noticeably changed either

Comment: From the [wiki](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://wikiwiki.jp/kairopark/%3F%25A5%25A2%25A5%25CB%25A5%25E1%25A5%25B9%25A5%25BF%25A5%25B8%25A5%25AA%25CA%25AA%25B8%25EC&usg=ALkJrhhslQF49Agns9lh6L0FQFDvgGPJCA), the school has the effect of, "Some applicants from good student".  So...perhaps one of the hiring options gives improved candidates?